# git partial clone garbage collection

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-gc

**Question:** How can I remove / prune / gc unreferenced blobs in a partially cloned git repository?

**Details:** I am evaluating whether [Git Partial Clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone) can become a replacement for Git LFS, now where both GitLab and GitHub seem to have implemented full support for it (I couldn't find a *beta* label). As large binaries / blobs are only fetched on checkout with `--filter=blob:none`, the git repository on disk and the fetch performance seem both reasonably fast.
That being said, I am struggling how to clean / prune the blobs similar to git LFS prune. When working with a reasonably sized repository over time, you still end up with all blobs that have accumulated over time that are not referenced by HEAD (anymore).

**What I've tried**: I was hoping that `git gc --prune=today --aggressive` would be able to understand the active filter (or that I can pass a filter) to convert all blobs / trees / commits, that are not referenced by the current checkout, to promisor objects. Unfortunately, I could not find a way to reduce the size of the partial cloned repository after using it for quite a while

**edit:** I am using git version 2.36.0

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: As far as I know, the promisor pack stuff only ever replaces an unfulfilled object with a fulfilled one, never going the other way. That is, the design currently precludes ejecting an object. There's no *design* reason for this but there's an obvious *implementation* one: there is no last-access-time in an object so there is no way to cache the objects appropriately.

Comment: Hence, to reduce the size of a partial clone, you just throw away the partial clone and make a new one. Erase, re-create, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Sure, re-cloning would work - I was just hoping for a "remove all but current checkout and active stashes" solution which would not require properties such as last-access-time. Asking the users to occasionally re-clone the repositories seem counter-intuitive

Comment: @Sc4v: That would require special-casing the "prune now" GC. It's certainly *possible* to do this, but unless there's a particularly strong use case for it, you'll probably just see the general case happen someday (if and when there's an auxiliary "last access time" database).

Comment: I found some further discussion and use cases [here](https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+M_GG1SfxGW=p_=418hdR1ypB3v-4GrooK6_75UUNJDb+kk2Q@mail.gmail.com)